# React Native - Array property of JSON object returns undefined, other properties all return a value

Tags: javascript, json, react-native

I'm quite new to React Native and I'm tearing my hair out trying to figure out why I can't access an array property of a JSON object.

My JSON object looks like this:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "items:": [
        {
            "description": "What is the current vehicle mileage?",
            "id": 1,
            "required": true,
            "title": "Mileage",
            "type": "Number"
        },
        {
            "description": "First aid kid present?",
            "id": 2,
            "required": true,
            "title": "Safety",
            "type": "Boolean"
        }
    ],
    "title": "Default Inspection Report"
}
```

And the code I'm using is:

```
import React from "react";
import { View, Text } from "react-native";

export default function VehicleInspection({ navigation, route }) {
  console.log(route.params.template.items);
  console.log(route.params.template);
  return (
    <View><Text>Title: {route.params.template.title}</Text></View>
  );
}
```

If I log `route.params.template` to the console it returns the whole object complete with the contents of the "items" array. If I log `route.params.template.items` to the console it returns undefined.

Returning `route.params.template.title` in the View component returns "Default Inspection Report" as expected.

Am I missing something really stupid here?

This is the console output from the code above:

```
undefined
Object {
  "id": 1,
  "items:": Array [
    Object {
      "description": "What is the current vehicle mileage?",
      "id": 1,
      "required": true,
      "title": "Mileage",
      "type": "Number",
    },
    Object {
      "description": "First aid kid present?",
      "id": 2,
      "required": true,
      "title": "Safety",
      "type": "Boolean",
    }
  ],
  "title": "Default Inspection Report",
}
```

Comment: the key is "items:" with a colon, prolly a typo

Comment: ^ lol. Man these typos bring our life expectancy down.

Comment: Oh my god. I ran the JSON through a validator just to check it was valid, I have no idea how I missed that. Thanks man!